# need to store date as per user timezone in php

Tags: php, date

i have simple php script where i have this variable

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', time());
```

**The Problem:** The variable is storing date as per my server timezone.

**What is want:** I want to store date as per user time zone, take a look into

> example below:

1- tom checkin from USA

2- jenne checkin from Asia
since there is 12 hrs. difference so the date will be different too sometime

here is found some example but it's not dynamic
[Converting GMT time to local time using timezone offset in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670298/converting-gmt-time-to-local-time-using-timezone-offset-in-php)

```
offset = '-0500';
$isDST = 1; // Daylight Saving 1 - on, 0 - off
$timezoneName = timezone_name_from_abbr('', intval($offset, 10) * 36, $isDST);
$timezone = new DateTimeZone($timezoneName);

Then you can use it in a DateTime constructor, e.g.

$datetime = new DateTime('2012-04-21 01:13:30', $timezone);
```

> Now what exactly i am looking,

1- in case of **TOM** $date should be **18**
11:38 PM
Tuesday, 18 April 2017 (GMT-5)
Time in Chicago, IL, USA

2- in case of **jenne** $date should be **19**
9:40 AM
Wednesday, 19 April 2017 (GMT+5)
Time in Lahore

Comment: Do you actually want to have current time with different timezones?

Comment: @SahilGulati, yep right now i am looking to convert america/chicago time now which is 11:38 PM
Tuesday, 18 April 2017 (GMT-5) (TO)
Wednesday, 19 April 2017 (GMT+5)
Time in Lahore

Comment: What you have offset or timezone for each user?

Comment: you should get the users timezone then use it with date_default_timezone_set('users timezone');

Comment: @gert, yup i already have user timezone in my db which every-time user login, let's take an example of if user time zone is (GMT+5) than what we need to do to get result like this ? $date = date('Y-m-d', time());

Comment: @SahilGulati, i have both offset or timezone for each user which i am storing in to db at the time they log in, than i am looking to store their date into another table using $date variable

Comment: you can do that way likewise my post, if you have timezone name of the user. you can store date in variable `$date` I have updated my post you can check it.

Comment: you get the users timezone and put it in a variable say $usertimezone then date_default_timezone_set("'".$usertimezone."'"); then create variable for date and use new date time and it will be the users time

Comment: @JamezRoz i posted a answer for you , tested it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

difficult writing code in the comments section so i posted a working answer for you here

```
<?php
// here $usertimezone should be set = to what you have in your database
$usertimezone="Asia/Shanghai"; 

date_default_timezone_set('"'.$usertimezone.'"'); 

//new date and time
$ndate= new datetime();
//split into date and time seperate
$nndate =$ndate->format("Y-m-d");
$nntime= $ndate->format("H:i:S");
//here you can test it
echo $nndate;
echo $nntime;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function `date_default_timezone_set` for setting timezone, From this function you can set the timezone according to user and then get the required format.

[**Examples**](https://eval.in/778773)

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("new/timezone");//set the name of timezone here example Asia/Kokata
echo $date= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: for example my time zone is (america/Chicago GMT-5) and i want to declare it as variable $date than how i can do this like this way ? $date = date('Y-m-d', time());